# Good introductory reference/lecture notes to finite element analysis for PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question, finite-element-method

I am a graduate student planning to take an introductory mathematical finite element theory course this fall.

**Is there any recommended, based on your experience, (preferably available online) source to familiarize myself with the field?**

I am particularly looking for a source that excels in explaining main ideas in a clear manner rather than going through long derivations and proofs (which I will get enough of during the semester!)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ciarlet's book is good. And everything is available online if you know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Professor Chen Long's FEM notes to you: [https://www.math.uci.edu/~chenlong/226/Ch2FEM.pdf](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Echenlong/226/Ch2FEM.pdf).